# Prove that $P\{X=k\}=\int_{0}^{1}{P\{X=k\vert p\}f(p)dp}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I read my book, and I stuck in this, "However, let us now suppose that whereas the trials all have the same success
probability p, its value is not predetermined but is chosen according to a uniform
distribution on (0, 1). In this
case, by conditioning on the actual value of p, we have
$$P\{X=k\}=\int_{0}^{1}{P\{X=k\vert p\}f(p)dp}=\int_{0}^{1}{{n\choose k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}dp}"$$

I don't see how determine the first equality, where $X$ denote the total number of successes, in $n$ independent trials, each of which is a success with probability p, any help pls!

Comment: For a uniformly distributed $p$, the density $f(p)=1$. The integrand in the last expression is $P\{X=k|p\}$, the binomial(n,p) density at $k$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't know for what reason $P\{X=k\}=\int_{0}^{1}{{n\choose k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}dp}$

Comment: This is rather general: for every event $A$ and random variable $U$, $P(A)=E(P(A\mid U))$ hence $$P(A)=\int P(A\mid U=u)f_U(u)du.$$ Here, $A=[X=k]$ and $U=p$ (notwithstanding a regrettable notational confusion between the random variable $p$ and its values $p$) hence, for every $u$ in $[0,1]$, $$P(A\mid U=u)={n\choose p}u^p(1-u)^{n-p}.$$